# ffmpeg stdout wrong timecode out

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, timecodes

If I run this command line

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 3600 -i file1.mp3 -ss 0 -t 20 -i file2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1" -ac 2 -f wav - > test.wav
```

I'm basically putting the stout inside a container wav (test.wav) but the duration is always wrong. The output file should be **01:00:20.00** but if I play it on VLC (or any player audio) it shows **06:12:49.00** and even if I change the start_times, the durations and number of files, I still get that timecode out. The even weirder thing is that ffprobe shows the duration as it should be. Can somebody please help me on this?

**UPDATE**:

```
[wav @ 0000000000cf3680] Ignoring maximum wav data size, file may be invalid
[wav @ 0000000000cf3680] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, wav, from 'test.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
    timecode        : 01:00:20.00
  Duration: 01:00:20.00, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

That is what the ffprobe on the output shows..the duration is correct here but not on any audio player

Comment: Show the properties for file1 and file2

Comment: `Input #0, mp3, from 'PMM_20170327-2100_1.mp3':
  Duration: 01:00:03.29, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
    Side data:
      replaygain: track gain - -0.200000, track peak - unknown, album gain - unknown, album peak - unknown`

Comment: And the 2nd file?

Comment: ops sorry `Input #1, mp3, from 'PMM_20170327-2200_1.mp3':
  Duration: 01:00:03.29, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
    Side data:
      replaygain: track gain - 1.800000, track peak - unknown, album gain - unknown, album peak - unknown,`

Comment: Try with `-f wav -rf64 always - ` and with `-f wav -rf64 never -`

Comment: `-rf64 always` worked!!!!! thank you so much for that!